# Python socket receiving corrupted information

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to understand how send and receive are working.

I was trying to send continuously data to a server and i noticed that the server would receive mixed bytes because i was sending to much data at a time. See my code:

Server:

```
import socket, struct

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server.bind(("",1996))

server.listen(0)

c,d = server.accept()

while True:

    data = c.recv(1024)
    print( struct.unpack("i", data)[0] )
```

Client:

```
import socket, struct

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server.connect(("192.168.1.4",1996))

while True:

    data = 1
    server.send( struct.pack("i", data) )
```

Then i change the while loops to this:

Server:

```
data = c.recv(1024)
print( struct.unpack("i", data)[0] )
c.send( str.encode("Server received your message. You now can continue 
sending more data") )
```

Client:

```
data = 1
server.send( struct.pack("i", data) )

#Wait to secure the send.
server.recv(1024)
```

This is working. I'm making sure that the client won't send data before the
server already receive the previous send.

But what if i want to do the same for the server too? How can i make sure that the server will send bytes to the client in a safe way?

I already tried this and i notice that i created an infinity loop because(I used multi-threading in order to send and receive at the same time on the server):

client was sending some data and then waiting to get a signal from the server
that he can send again.

the server was getting some data then sending the signal and after that waiting for a signal from the user that he can send again.

But because the client was actually sending data again, the whole thing was going on again and this caused me an infinity talk-reply loop.

So what can i do to make a continuously conversation between two sockets without mixing the bytes together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by [Nagle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) which works by combining a number of small outgoing messages, and sending them all at once as TCP is a stream protocol. You can enable `TCP_NODELAY` socket option by calling [`sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setsockopt) to  sent data as soon as possible, even if there is only a small amount of data. And on the receiver side, it isn't going to get one packet at a time either, you must implement message boundaries itself if you want "continuous conversation between two sockets without mixing the bytes together".